# Grey Out Area Using Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

How can I grey out a whole pageblock using Visualforce? This is to give user the idea that all records contained in an area are locked and can't be edited. Meanwhile, here's my vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c">
     <apex:form>
          <apex:pageBlock>
               <apex:inputField value={!Custom_Object__c.Name}/>
               <apex:inputField value={!Custom_Object__c.Company__c}/>
               <apex:inputField value={!Custom_Object__c.Type__c}/>
               <apex:inputField value={!Custom_Object__c.Revenue__c}/>
          </apex:pageBlock> 
     </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident there are many solutions to this. One that I know of is very old. It involves using CSS and the [z-index property](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#propdef-z-index). You'd want to put the above items in a table where that "sat" on top of an image that was opaque, meaning it had a certain amount of transparency, say 80 to 90%. You'd also specify a background color for your table.

When you wanted to "dim" any of your items or all of them, you'd change the z-index of the table cells that contained the opaque images so they were located above the cells you wanted to darken or "dim". That's what was originally called DHTML. You could do this using JS or JQuery if you wanted.